Javascript, map array from index
How is it possible to map an array from a index and then map the rest based on a criteria.


const array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6];

const map = array.map((x, index) => {
  if(x<8){
    return index;
  };
 
});

console.log(">> "+map);

// Output array should be [1,3,4,5];  * Final array will be a lot bigger;



For example I want to search the array from index 1 and then return the indexes of all values less than 8.
Is map the best way or is there another?
Any help / advice would be appreciated.

you need to use filter+map combination because map alone will give an array the same size as your input array. map is for transforming each element in an array

Why shouldn't 0 be in the result?

You could also use reduce() to do the mapping and filtering at once.

You can filter out the undefined values that are returned for the elements that don't match the condition.


const array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6];

const result = array.map((x, index) => {
  if(x<8){
    return index;
  };
}).filter(el => el !== undefined);

console.log(">> "+result);



Or do it in one loop using reduce.


const array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6];

const result = array.reduce((acc, x, index) => {
  if(x<8){
    acc.push(index);
  };
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(">> "+result);




Thanks - perfect.  The first example works best for me.

You could get all indices of the array and filter by value of the same indices.


const
    array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6],
    indices = [...array.keys().filter(i => array[i] < 8)];

console.log(indices);



Or directly with entries, filter and mapping the index


const
    array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6],
    indices = [...array
        .entries()
        .filter(([, v]) => v < 8)
        .map(([i]) => i)
    ];

console.log(indices);




If you want to use an Array method like .map() wherein the return value is transformed (ex. current number to current index) but return nothing when a criteria is not met (ie filtering), try .flatMap(). .flatMap() is like map() but it will flatten the returned array (see .flat()). The example below uses a ternary operator for the the criteria which means:

If the current index (i) is greater than OR equal to the given number (start = 1) ...
i >= start 


AND...
&&


the current value (x) is less than 8...
x < 8


return the current index (i).
? i


Otherwise return an empty array (which will be flattened to nothing).
: []





const array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6];
const start = 1;

const result = array.flatMap((x, i) => i >= start && x < 8 ? i : []);

console.log(">> "+result);

/** 
 * Output array should be [1,3,4,5];  
 * Final array will be NOT be bigger because the callback function returns 
 * just an index number OR nothing at all for a given number value
 */




I think this is the best way (that races over the array only once):


// Added more 5 positions for didactic purposes.
const myArray = [4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6, 15, 12, 11, 7, 25];

function indexesWithMaxValueOf ( theArray, theMaxValue, includeMax = true, startingIndex = 0 )
{
  const theIndexes = [];
  
  // Loops theArray only once.
  for ( const currentIndex in theArray )
  {
    // If you really need to skip some indexes...
    if ( currentIndex < startingIndex ) continue;
    
    if ( includeMax ? ( theArray[currentIndex] <= theMaxValue ) : ( theArray[currentIndex] < theMaxValue ) )
    {
      theIndexes.push(Number.parseInt(currentIndex));
    }
  }
  
  return theIndexes;
}

// TESTS:
console.log('myArray =', JSON.stringify(myArray));

console.log('indexesOfMaxValue(myArray, 8) =', JSON.stringify(indexesWithMaxValueOf(myArray, 8)));
console.log('indexesOfMaxValue(myArray, 7) =', JSON.stringify(indexesWithMaxValueOf(myArray, 7)));
console.log('indexesOfMaxValue(myArray, 6) =', JSON.stringify(indexesWithMaxValueOf(myArray, 6)));
console.log('indexesOfMaxValue(myArray, 5) =', JSON.stringify(indexesWithMaxValueOf(myArray, 5)));
console.log('indexesOfMaxValue(myArray, 4) =', JSON.stringify(indexesWithMaxValueOf(myArray, 4)));
console.log('indexesOfMaxValue(myArray, 3) =', JSON.stringify(indexesWithMaxValueOf(myArray, 3)));
console.log('indexesOfMaxValue(myArray, 2) =', JSON.stringify(indexesWithMaxValueOf(myArray, 2)));
console.log('indexesOfMaxValue(myArray, 1) =', JSON.stringify(indexesWithMaxValueOf(myArray, 1)));



NOTE 1: The includeMax parameter (the third) has the default value of true. This means that when the third parameter is true (by default) then the comparison would be made using <= theMaxValue instead of < theMaxValue. To achieve what you asked, just use false as the third parameter and the comparison would be made using < theMaxValue.
NOTE 2: The startingIndex parameter (the fourth) has the default value of 0. Which means the function will verify by default starting from the very first element of the array. To achieve what you asked, just use 1 as the fourth parameter and the function will skip any index that is less than 1.
NOTE 3: You can add the default value of 8 to the theMaxValue parameter (the second) and alter the third and fourth parameters defaults to false and 1 respectively, and then the function will work exactly like you want with only one parameter.
